# Change authorization / login page

Tags: php, bitrix

For self-hosted Bitrix24

What is the approach to change the "authorization page" / login page?

Do we need to rebuild the whole Bitrix24 from the source just to change the login page?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need change `templates` for component `system.auth.form`.

All standart components of Bitrix are in `/bitrix/components/bitrix`.

If you want change template of component `system.auth.form`, put new theme (copy dir `.default` in `/bitrix/components/bitrix/system.auth.form/templates/.default`) to `/local/templates/.default/components/bitrix/system.auth.form` and edit it.